# Python xlsxwriter

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I want to make a excel file with different formats.
name of sheets and formats and row number has been saved in a list and then I want to use it in a for clause. but it shows me error:
lists

```
`lists=[
[4,'# Completed Orders','orderFormat'],
[5,'% Completed Orders (Website)','orderFormatpercent']]`

`for i,j in enumerate(lists):
    cell=xl_rowcol_to_cell((lists[i][0])-1,2)
    text=lists[i][1]
    formating=lists[i][2]
    ws1.write(cell,text,formating)`
```

Comment: Why do you have backquotes around your code?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You don’t need to use `xl_rowcol_to_cell()`. You can use the row and column numbers directly in `write()`.

Comment: No I don't have backquotes @cco

the error I am getting error about wb.close
actually I a getting error because of "formating" in there I can not put variable and don't know how to fix it

Comment: Show the error you are getting.  There is no reason to make us guess.  You should also fix the code in your question so it matches what you are trying to run.